# Non local static viariable as members of a class

Tags: c++

There are several questions out there about `static` variables, but I have not yet found an answer to my question. I just read [Scott Meyers' explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578571/c-what-is-difference-between-static-local-variablemethod-vs-globalfile-va) on the initialization of `static` variables and possible issues with it, like the *static initialization order fiasco*. What I would like to know is this: are `static` variables at class scope considered non-local?

Most sources I have seen say that `static` non local variables are defined either at global `namespace` or in a `namespace` while `static` local variables are defined in functions. But consider these two translations unit:

```
// MyClass.h:
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int z; // Is this non local?
};

// MyClass.cpp:
int MyClass::z = 4;

// MyOtherClass.h:
class MyOtherClass
{
public:
    static int w;
};

// MyOtherClass.cpp:
int MyOtherClass::w = MyClass::z; // Potential fiasco?
```

Is `z` non local? In other words, can we assume `z` is initialized when `w` is?

Comment: Static members are just glorified globals. Different translation units means SIFO. Your example is exactly what Meyers is talking about.

Comment: Everything that isn't declared inside a function is non-local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `MyClass::z` and `MyOtherClass::w` are non-local, static variables.

Your example potentially contains problems.

It's because `MyOtherClass::w` refers to `MyClass::z`, which potentially (from the viewpoint of compiling MyOtherClass) requires dynamic initialization [basic.start.static/3]:

> An implementation is permitted to perform the initialization of a
>   variable with static or thread storage duration as a static
>   initialization even if such initialization is not required to be done
>   statically, provided that
>
> - the dynamic version of the
>     initialization does not change the value of any other object of static
>     or thread storage duration prior to its initialization, and
> - **the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were initialized dynamically.**
>
> [ Note: As a consequence, if
>   the initialization of an object obj1 refers to an object obj2 of
>   namespace scope potentially requiring dynamic initialization and
>   defined later in the same translation unit, it is unspecified whether
>   the value of obj2 used will be the value of the fully initialized obj2
>   (because obj2 was statically initialized) or will be the value of obj2
>   merely zero-initialized. For example,

```
inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
extern double d1;
double d2 = d1;     // unspecified:
                    // may be statically initialized to 0.0 or
                    // dynamically initialized to 0.0 if d1 is
                    // dynamically initialized, or 1.0 otherwise 
double d1 = fd();   // may be initialized statically or dynamically to 1.0
```

> — end note ]

So when the compiler compiles MyOtherClass.cpp, it doesn't know which way `MyClass::z` will be actually initialized, so it falls into the "not required to be initialized statically" category. And then it is unspecified, what value `MyOtherClass::w` will have. It could have

- 0, when the compiler choose to statically initialize it
- 4, if the compiler choose to dynamically initialize it

Thanks to StoryTeller for drawing attention to this.

Comment: "because its value known at compile time": is this because I have used `int`s in my example? Would the potential fiasco arise with more complex types?

Comment: static initialization happens strongly before any dynamic initialization, but there is no guarantee the constant initialization of `z` will happen before `w`. Your are very misleading.

Comment: @BobMorane: Not necessarily. If you have a complex class, but it has a constexpr constructor (which is used to initialize it), then it will be statically initialized as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller: if `MyClass::z` is not statically initialized, then my answer is absolutely wrong, so I'll delete it.

Comment: @geza - The issue is not `z`, but `w`. I believe [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#3) applies. Which means the value of `w` can be unspecified.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Hmm, at first read, I don't think that contradicts what I've said.

Comment: The initialization of `w` doesn't modify any other object, and doesn't depend on any object initialized dynamically. Ergo, the implementation is permitted to initialize `w` statically. Which removes any sequencing guarantees. If you don't see this as a major caveat in what you said.. well..

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's true, but the value must be the same: "provided that the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were initialized dynamically."

Comment: All the variables not required to be initialized statically is an empty set. The condition is vacuously true.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I think that you are right, but not because it is an empty set. Quite the contrary. When compiling MyOtherClass.cpp, `z` has potentially dynamic initialization.